# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template A form can only be submitted once

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a error in symfony2 when i'am trying to submit a post in my app

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("A
>   form can only be submitted once") in
>   SmartnodeTalkBundle:Talk:viewchan.html.twig at line 24.

there is a gist with my code

https://gist.github.com/aurelben/9780465

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 9):

It's just a duplicated "$form->handleRequest($request)"in my code

now it's work